# How do I get this function to accept values that can either be floats or arrays or lists?

Tags: python, function, numpy, loops

Hi there I am having trouble with my code for a function I am adapting based on a previous code where I manually typed in the data:

I updated my code to be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def pitch(X0,Y0,Z0,V0MPH,RPM,GyroAngle,TiltAngle,Phi,Theta,WS,WD,Temp,RH,Pressure):
    for x0 in X0:
        for y0 in Y0:
            for z0 in Z0:
                for V0 in V0MPH:
                    for R in RPM:
                        for a in GyroAngle:
                            for b in TiltAngle:
                                for phi in Phi:
                                    for theta in Theta:
                                        for spd in WS:
                                            for dire in WD:
                                                for Tf in Temp:
                                                    for H in RH:
                                                        for P in Pressure:
                                                            uwindfts=spd*np.sin(dire) #U Wind in ft/s
                                                            vwindfts=spd*np.cos(dire) #V Wind in ft/s
                                                            timestep=0 #time step for calculating
                                                            dt=0.001 #D-time
                                                            circ=9.125 #Circumference of ball
                                                            phi=phi*np.pi/180
                                                            theta=theta*np.pi/180
                                                            if phi>0: #Angle pitch is released wrt HP-2B line
                                                                a=1
                                                            else:
                                                                a=-1
                                                            Tc=(Tf-32.0)*(5/9) #F to C
                                                            Tk=Tc+273.15 #C to K
                                                            dryrho=P*100/(287*Tk) #Density
                                                            ep=RH*0.01*6.11*np.exp(17.625*Tc/(243.05+Tc))
                                                            wetrho=ep*100/(461*Tk)
                                                            rho=dryrho-wetrho
                                                            # print(rho)
                                                            gyrospin=R*np.sin(a*np.pi/180)
                                                            sidespin=a*(R-gyrospin)*np.sin(b*np.pi/180)
                                                            backspin=-1*(R-gyrospin)*np.cos(b*np.pi/180)
                                                            v=V0*1.467 
                                                            c0=(0.07182*rho*0.06261)
                                                            vx=v*np.cos(theta*np.pi/180)*np.sin(phi*np.pi/180)
                                                            vy=v*np.cos(theta*np.pi/180)*np.cos(phi*np.pi/180)
                                                            vz=v*np.sin(theta*np.pi/180)
                                                            vwow=np.sqrt((vx-uwindfts)**2+(vy-vwindfts)**2+(vz)**2)
                                                            # print (womg)
                                                            # print (vz)
                                                            # print (vz+wvv)
                                                            # print (vz-wvv)
                                                            constk=np.pi/30.0
                                                            x=x0
                                                            y=y0
                                                            z=z0
                                                            while y >=(17/12):
                                                                visco=2.791*(10.0**-7)*(Tk**0.7355)
                                                                vre=v*(0.44704/1.4617)
                                                                Re=rho*(vre)*(circ*0.254/(np.pi))/visco
                                                                upper=74.1*1.467*210000.0/Re
                                                                lower=14.3*1.467*210000.0/Re
                                                                cd=0.5-(0.227/(1.0+np.exp(-1.0*(v-upper)/lower)))
                                                                dragx=-cd*c0*vwow*(vx-uwindfts)
                                                                dragy=-cd*c0*vwow*(vy-vwindfts)
                                                                dragz=-cd*c0*vwow*(vz)
                                                                omgx=constk*(backspin*np.cos(phi)-(sidespin*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi))+gyrospin*vx/vwow)
                                                                omgy=constk*(-1*backspin*np.sin(phi)-(sidespin*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi))+gyrospin*vy/vwow)
                                                                omgz=constk*(sidespin*np.cos(theta)+gyrospin*(vz/vwow))
                                                                omg=np.sqrt(omgx**2.0+omgy**2.0+omgz**2.0)
                                                                romg=omg*(circ/(2.0*np.pi))/12.0
                                                                S=np.exp((timestep*dt)/1000.0)*(romg/vwow)
                                                                cl=1.0/(2.32+(0.4/S))
                                                                magnusx=c0*(cl/omg)*vwow*(omgy*(vz)-omgz*(vy-vwindfts))
                                                                magnusy=c0*(cl/omg)*vwow*(omgz*(vx-uwindfts)-omgx*(vz))
                                                                magnusz=c0*(cl/omg)*vwow*(omgx*(vy-vwindfts)-omgy*(vx-uwindfts))
                                                                ax=magnusx+dragx
                                                                ay=magnusy+dragy
                                                                az=magnusz+dragz-32.174
                                                                vx=vx+ax*dt
                                                                vy=vy-ay*dt
                                                                vz=vz+az*dt
                                                                v=np.sqrt((vx)**2+(vy)**2+vz**2)
                                                                vwow=np.sqrt((vx-uwindfts)**2+(vy-vwindfts)**2+(vz)**2)
                                                                x=x+vx*dt+ax*(dt**2)
                                                                y=y+vy*dt+ay*(dt**2)
                                                                z=z+vz*dt+az*(dt**2)
                                                                vmph=v/1.467
                                                                timestep+=1
                                                                xfinal=x
                                                                zfinal=z
                                                                print (xfinal,zfinal) 
                                                                return xfinal,zfinal

pitch(-2.5,55,6,95,2450,5,183,176.5,-2,5,0,72,55,1013.25)
```

in order to read arrays but the new code doesn't want to read float.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QffcA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K6wt.png

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: (1) You posted about 75 lines of code for a 5-line problem.  (2) Once you've reduced your code to the MRE, explain in particular where you're confused about the error.  By now, you've looked up the message and (maybe) understand the mechanics.  Do you not know how to properly vectorize whatever operation you want to use, or do you have trouble with representing your data in a legally meaningful fashion?

Comment: That was rude @Prune as I have a disability so I might not know everything

Comment: `y` starts as a number, but in the loop becomes a array.  That can't be used in the `while` test.  Ambiguity errors like this have been discussed in many SO questions.

Comment: I am trying to help you edit your post into something that fits the SO posting standard, rather than something that gets down-voted and deleted.  This has nothing to do with a disability, nor with how much you know.  Those are leading questions to focus your post, examples of what you might need to ask.

Comment: @hpaulj how can I fix it.

Comment: As you've noticed, now that you focused your post, you have one response ... and a second, if this turns out to be within my capabilities.  We still need the *entire* error message, as the posting guidelines tell you.  Include the traceback.

Comment: I can't run your code: `Tk` is undefined.  It's hard to read with the abbreviated variable names, but I expect those nicely match your source equation.  Please trace whatever value is causing the problem; `hpaulj` says it's `y`, but I don't see where the type changes.

Comment: I had to shorten the code as you said.

Comment: But i added the crucial details because of how you said Tk is missing.

Comment: if `y` is array - ie. `[2.0, 0, 1.8]` - and you check `y>=17/12` then it gets array `[True, False, True]` and it doesn't know if it should treat it as single `True` or single `False` - and it ask you to use `any()` or `all()`  - ie, `any(y>=17/12)` or `all(y>=17/12)` and then it will run `any([True, False, True])` or `all([True, False, True])` to get single `True` or single `False`.

Comment: The fix depends on what you want to happen.  Should `y` be an array?  If so, what's the right test for quiting the loop.  If you understand the error, the fix should be obvious. If you are using code without understanding what it's supposed to do, we can't help you.

Comment: at start you could use `print()` to see values in variables - ie, `print(y, y>=17/12)` - and maybe then you will know what is the problem.

Comment: y is not exactly an array as the RPM is the array so I can see what the different RPMs do to the X and Z.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how array `RMP` propagates through to `y`.  `y` starts as a single number, but once that iteration is done, it is an array with the same shape as `RMP` (if I've read the code right).

```
def pitchtrack(x,y,z,RPM,v0mph,gyro,tiltangle,phi,theta,wu,wv,wvv,Tf,RH,Pmb):
    ....
    backspin=-1*(RPM-gyrospin)*np.cos(a*tiltangle*np.pi/180)
    ...
    while y>=(17/12):
       ...
       omgx=np.pi*(backspin*np.cos(phi*np.pi/180.0)
       ...
       magnusy=c0*(cl/omg)*vwow*(omgz*(vx-wu)-omgx*(vz))
       ...
       ay=magnusy+dragy
       ...
       vy=vy-ay*dt
       ...
       y=y+vy*dt
       ...
```

`y>=(7/12)` will then be a boolean array with multiple values.  That's what the error is all about.  Such an array CANNOT be used in a Python context that expects ONE boolean value.  Examples include `if`, `or` and here, `while`.

The error message suggests using `any` or `all` to reduce that array to one value. But you have to decide which is the right one.  Sometimes other things might be used, such as `sum` or `max/min`, or other means of reducing the multiple values to one.

Are you sure the author of this code intended for `RMP` to be an array?  Maybe it was written with a scalar value in mind - and tested with such!

Comment: I am the author and I was testing RPM as an array so I can test out other methods such as like how changing the temperature affects the movement.

Comment: While plotting all the different outcomes on the same graph.

Comment: Then you need to pay attention to how array dimensions propagate through the calculation, and take that into account.